# Linux - Linebreak in IPython

Tags: python, linux, shell, ipython, line-breaks

Hi I'm new to Linux and I really like the idea of writing and testing python code in a shell. But my problem is how can I do line breaks in IPython. Every time I use the (I think) "normal" shortcut shift+enter the code gets executed. Function keys are disabled and keyboard layout works fine on my laptop, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is the problem. Python code is executed line-by-line.

If your code does not work when executed line-by-line, it should not work when loaded from a file (assuming in both cases a "clean" environment).

Comment: Thanks for reply @Marcin! If I want to write a function or something similar in Ipython I need more than one line to describe it in the right way (indentation) or I'm wrong? When I send `def myfunction:` to the compiler always a error appears.

Comment: @danny That is an error because `def myfunction:` is not valid python anywhere.

Comment: Ahh you're right! `def myfunction():`, Sry I'am new to python too ;)

Answer (score 17):

I just came across a solution, posted by Kenneth Falck:
[IPython newlines with ^V^J](https://coderwall.com/p/2bdenw)

While editing a multiline code block use `Ctrl+V CTRL+J`

Comment: Thanks! This was killing me when trying to edit previous blocks in IPython.

Comment: FYI: in a terminal program like iTerm2, you can assign this to one hotkey. I set ctrl-enter to "Send hex codes" of 0x16 0x0a. Could also use cmd-enter or whatever else is most comfortable to you.

Comment: This problem turned me off ipython for a while. Now I am back! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do a line-break, you end the line with the `\` escape character, same as you do in a Python file. `Shift+Enter` doesn't have any special meaning in `ipython`, and indeed most over places in the shell. It doesn't have special meaning in Python, either.

It does have special meaning in some text editors and word processors, most notably LyX and LibreOffice, and of course on some websites (through a web browser).